# How to migrate containerized app to Visual Studio?

Tags: docker-compose, visual-studio-2019

Is there a way to run and debug a solution with custom pre-existing docker-compose and DOCKERFILEs when migrating to Visual Studio?

I'll try to elaborate as requested:

I'm working on a .Net Core project with multiple services (web APIs), each one with a respective DOCKERFILE. The containers and their dependencies are built and run via a compose file which is used for CD purposes and is optimized for our needs, but I can't use it together with VS2019 because the IDE doesn't recognize these files, and forces the creation of a new docker-compose (in the solutions' root folder) and DOCKERFILE when I attempt to add orchestrator support to any of the projects. These behavior results in the error message "the file ./docker-compose.yml already exists" and the creation of the docker-compose project fails (I'm following the instructions from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/tutorial-multicontainer?view=vs-2019)

I don't want pollute my repository with the files generated by Visual Studio, but the naming convention used by the IDE makes ignoring them not as simple as it should (IMHO).

So, my question is, is it possible to use a custom docker-compose and DOCKERFILEs when adding container orchestrator support to my projects in Visual Studio?

Comment: try to show us what you have tried.. to help others to post the appropriate answer for you

Comment: @AAEM , I've tryed to elaborate.